# Unmarshal a modified xml file

Tags: java, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

In my java project I need to unmarshal an xml file in order to get a list of objects.

The unmarshalling works very fine but the problem is encontourned when the content of the file is modified. In fact in this project we can add new contents to this file by clicking on "addButon" but when i want  to unmarshal another time the same file (after modification) i get only the old list of objects without the last elements (I have just added to this file).

I already verified the physical xml file on the disk and I found all the last content I just added. Also I noticed that The only way to get the last list of objects is to close the appli and to reopen it again, which is unsuitable.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
//classe1.java

File iniFile = new File(proprietesPerle.getRepRef() + "referential.xml");

FileInputStream fs = = new FileInputStream(iniFile);

ref = Referentiel.unmarshal(fs);    

TreeMap map = ReferentielUtil.getApplication( ref );

...


//classe2.java

TreeMap map = new TreeMap();

List         listPL = app.getPl(); //this list is unmarshalled from the xml file

ListIterator itpl    = listPL.listIterator();

while (itpl.hasNext())
 {

   Pl pl = (Pl)itpl.next();

   map.put(pl.getCode(), pl);
 }

return map;

...
```

---

Thank you so much Igor for your response

```
In fact we select an app from a combobox, it's type is "Application" and this variable is stocked in a session. we use it like this:

session.setAttribute("selectedApplication",selectedAppli); 
TreeMap mapp = ReferentielUtil.getPl(selectedAppli.getApp());

//Class ReferentielUtil.java
public static TreeMap getPl(Application app)
{
    logger.debug("getPl");
    logger.debug("passe 10");
    TreeMap map = new TreeMap();

    List  listPL = app.getPl();
    ListIterator itpl    = listPL.listIterator();
    while (itpl.hasNext())
    {
        Pl pl = (Pl)itpl.next();

        map.put(pl.getCode(), pl);
    }
    return map;
}

inside Referentiel.unmarshal, you will find a code like this:

 public void unmarshal(Unmarshaller u)
    throws UnmarshalException
{

    XMLScanner xs = u.scanner();
    xs.takeStart("application");
    while (xs.atAttribute()) {
        String an = xs.takeAttributeName();
        throw new InvalidAttributeException(an);
    }
    if (xs.atStart("code")) {
        xs.takeStart("code");
        String s;
        if (xs.atChars(XMLScanner.WS_COLLAPSE)) {
            s = xs.takeChars(XMLScanner.WS_COLLAPSE);
        } else {
            s = "";
        }
        try {
            _Code = String.valueOf(s);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            throw new ConversionException("code", x);
        }
        xs.takeEnd("code");
    }
    if (xs.atStart("libelle")) {
        xs.takeStart("libelle");
        String s;
        if (xs.atChars(XMLScanner.WS_COLLAPSE)) {
            s = xs.takeChars(XMLScanner.WS_COLLAPSE);
        } else {
            s = "";
        }
        try {
            _Libelle = String.valueOf(s);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            throw new ConversionException("libelle", x);
        }
        xs.takeEnd("libelle");
    }
    _TypeApplication = ((TypeApplication) u.unmarshal());
    if (xs.atStart("entite")) {
        xs.takeStart("entite");
        String s;
        if (xs.atChars(XMLScanner.WS_COLLAPSE)) {
            s = xs.takeChars(XMLScanner.WS_COLLAPSE);
        } else {
            s = "";
        }
        try {
            _Entite = String.valueOf(s);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            throw new ConversionException("entite", x);
        }
        xs.takeEnd("entite");
    }
    {
        List l = PredicatedLists.create(this, pred_Pl, new ArrayList());
        while (xs.atStart("pl")) {
            l.add(((Pl) u.unmarshal())); // the problem is here : unmarshal() dont gives the last element --------------
        }
        _Pl = PredicatedLists.createInvalidating(this, pred_Pl, l);
    }
    xs.takeEnd("application");  

}

I noticed that in (while loop) we dont get the last element Pl which we want to add to the list "l"

Please do you have any idea?
```

Comment: Don't use raw types. Use generics: `List<Pl>`, `ListIterator<Pl>`, and `TreeMap<Integer, Pl>` (assuming `pl.getCode()` is of type `int`).

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help but the project use only java 1.4 so we can't use generics. When i use it i get this error: "Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5"

Answer (score 0):

Yep, really, looks like you don't close/flush the outputStream object. Try that, it should help.

Comment: Thank you Igor for your help. I already used fs.flush() and fs.close() in finally clause but it still doesn't work. Please do you have another idea?

Comment: I'm afraid that the code you provided looks ok... I would need to see a little more: what is the "app" variable, what happens inside the Referentiel.unmarshal method?

Comment: Thank you Igor i posted an answer to your questions

Comment: in your first example, you pass FileInputStream to the method Referentiel.unmarshal, but in the second example it takes Unmarshaller as a parameter... how do you create it?
I'm sorry, I don't know the answer, I'm just trying to ask questions that could lead us to a solution.

Comment: Yes your right, it is a successive call of methods. You can imagine that methode1(object1 o1) -> call methode2(object2 o2) -> call the last method unmarshal (i posted here)

Comment: Well, I have two propositions. One: at the point where you open the file for reading, add a test block that would just print out the contents of the file. This way, you will be sure that nothing is cached, the file is ok. Two: you get the wrong data inside the unmarshaller, so if the point one is ok, it must be the unmarshaller  that is wrong. Try re-creating your object if you are reusing the old one (just for the test). Can you show me the chain of calls from unmarshal(FileINputStream) to unmarshal(Unmarshaller u)?